# Android app apk not getting installed from file filemanager

Tags: android

When I share my apk through Google Drive or any means App is not getting installed on some phones. But when I install it through ADB it is getting installed. What could be the problem?

Comment: goto your phone settings->security enable `unknown source` then install

Comment: I have already done that.

Answer (score 0):

there are many reason , maybe you use native code , or issue with signing.
try to install though ADB in release variant and check the error .
in android section at your app level gradle file "`build.gradle module app` add your signing config

```
.........
android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        storeFile file('path to your keystore file')
        storePassword 'keystorePassword'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'aliesPassword'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
.......
```

then from the left side click build variant and choose release
[image]

now run your app and you should get the same result as install the APK from file manager or what ever .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio 3.0 above version and trying to build an APK then go to

1. Go to build
   2: Build bundles 
   3: Build APK(s)

and then share the build. It will surely get installed in any devices. 
Just make sure Device has allowed APK install from other resources.